# Which fantasy work first showed dragons?

Tags: history-of, fantasy-genre

Dragons possibly have an origin in Chinese mythologies, but I am not looking for mythologies. Lots of modern fantasy works have borrowed the concept of fire-breathing flying creatures. e.g. Harry Potter, The Hobbit, Game of Thrones etc.

Which one was the first to borrow the concept?

Comment: What is your definition of "modern fantasy works?" For example, would fairy tales from the Bros. Grimm fit your definition? What about the orally transmitted legend of St. George?

Comment: @Lexible They should be published.

Comment: The Saint George story was written down and published in XIII Speculum Historiale https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_George_and_the_Dragon

Comment: This is an unanswerable question : precisely because they _are_ mythological (as you state you are aware of) : they existed in myth since before literature & have been burrowed from it from literature's beginnings so unless you want to fix a date & say something like "which is the first novel published in 1945 or later to incorporate dragons" answers can only be opinion based & by definition every opinion ("answer") will be wrong because there's always an earlier example : the question really needs editing or deleting.

Comment: @Yasskier I'm sure there are earlier examples from China & Japan that were published, & when was Beowulf written? : you probably couldn't get a panel of history professors to agree an answer for this because they'd be going so far back some of the entities from "published" works they'd be talking about would begin to fall into categories where it was a matter of opinion if they qualified as dragons or not.

Comment: ^ and then someone would start arguing about what qualified as "published", did it have to be a still existing company or did dissolved companies that had published under still extant publishing laws count, what about the publishing laws of ancient nations that no longer exist etc etc..

Comment: @Pelinore I agree with you - VTC until there will be bit more specification.

Comment: You might as well ask the first work of fantasy fiction to contain a sword or a hat. Along with dragons, they existed before people started writing things down and are pretty much ubiquitous.

Answer (score 5):

Dragons (or at least a monstrous beast that's covered in scales that fits the description of a dragon) first appear in fantastic fiction in our old friend [The Epic of Gilgamesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh) from 2100BC, literally the first work of published fiction. The beast Humbaba is described thusly;

> "he had the paws of a lion and a body covered in thorny scales; his
>   feet had the claws of a vulture, and on his head were the horns of a
>   wild bull; his tail and phallus each ended in a snake's head.

We also see him breathing fire

> Enlil assigned (Humbaba) as a terror to human beings,
>   Humbaba's roar is a Flood, his mouth is Fire, and his breath is Death!
>   He can hear 100 leagues away any rustling in his forest!
>   Who would go down into his forest!
>   Enlil assigned him as a terror to human beings,
>   and whoever goes down into his forest paralysis will strike!"

Which all sounds pretty dragon-like to me.

---

Note that since dragons are mythological and pre-date writing, they crop up in pretty much every early work of fantastic fiction, including several other potential candidates from Gilgamesh (Kur?) and The [Exploits of Ninurta](http://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/section1/tr162.htm). You might also look at the legends of Cadmus, Ladon and Python in Greek Myth.

Comment: Could Humbaba fly?

Comment: @Endgame - It's not clear from the text, but we know that his brother is Pazuzu Demon of the Wind and who most certainly does have wings. Possibly it's a family trait.

Comment: Humbaba, I thought he was a giant? Pazuzu I know was depicted as a winged humanoid.

Comment: @Pelinore - Depends on the translation. In some he's depicted as having a face made of entrails, in others he's a giant, in [others](https://archive.org/details/gilgamescheineer00burcuoft/page/n3) he's a sort of proto-dragon. If you don't like Humbaba as a dragon, Kur (also from Gilgamesh) is definitely so, albeit not fire-breathing as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well if Paz is his brother then his dads a god, he was probably some sort of embodiment of the forest the same as his brother was an embodiment of the sky or wind, these early demi-god types often had pretty mutable forms, especially when they belonged to a culture that grew old with them, the Chinese whispers of generations can really mess with your self image if your not careful.